# Can I write code in SOASTA CloudTest? or, the right way to test a RESTful service in CloudTest

Tags: rest, performance-testing

In my last job, I did load testing using Gatling.  I loved it.

In my new job, they have Soasta CloudTest.  At first blush, it looks like a nice tool.

However, all I can find is information about record-and-playback.  I am not a fan of record-and-playback for many reasons, which I will not reiterate here.

But just because I can't find anything other than record-and-playback doesn't mean it can't do it.  It just means that the tool is best known for its record-and-playback capabilities, as that is a selling point when marketing to novice testers that do not have a development background.

My question is, can I do code-based development in CloudTest?  Can someone point me to documentation on how to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am a performance engineer at SOASTA, the makers of CloudTest.

CloudTest is designed for script development to take place in its UI. You can manually create web service requests there, but that still takes place inside of the interface. I don't think you can move exclusively to a text editor.

A few CloudTest abstraction techniques that may be relevant to what you want to accomplish:

- Chaining of smaller test script objects for code encapsulation/re-use in and across script groups and scenarios.
- JavaScript components written/maintained in one place, then reused and referenced from multiple scripts.
- Java Custom Modules: CloudTest scripts call Java JAR files using JavaScript calls.
- Flow control with dynamic properties, based on server responses, JavaScript code, or external(seed) data (csv file or database query).
- Tools for testing in CI/CD pipelines, referencing already prepared test scenarios. Once those are built, they can be executed from command line scripts.

There is a community site at [cloudlink.soasta.com](http://cloudlink.soasta.com) with documentation and videos on how to use these techniques. If you'd like to discuss any of this in more detail, I would be happy to connect directly.

Comment: Sadly, I was afraid that would be the case.  Which means I am going to push for using Gatling instead of CloudTest.